# how to pass csrf-token to 2nd API call without validation issue in IONIC angular

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework, access-token, csrf-token

There are 2 SAP API's which I want to use 1st API gets me the x-csrf-token from header which I need to pass to 2nd API as request header.
1st API call

```
fetchIsAliveSetDetails(token,order){
    console.log("INSIDE fetchIsAliveSetDetails");
    
      const httpOptions: Object = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'x-csrf-token': 'fetch',
          'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*'
      }),
        observe: 'response',
    };
    this.http.get<any>(this.isAliveSetURL, httpOptions).pipe(first()).subscribe(
      (res)  => {
       var csrfToken = res.headers.get("x-csrf-token");
       this.sendOrderSet(order,csrfToken,this.oAuthToken);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        return "error";
      }
    );
  }
```

response

[image]

This x-csrf-token is passed to the 2nd API call but when I hit the 2nd API it says the CSRF token validation failed
Code for 2nd API call

```
sendOrderSet(order,xToken,token){
      const httpOptions: Object = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'x-csrf-token':xToken,
          'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,
          'content-type':'application/json'
      }),
      //withCredentials:true
    };
    this.http.post(this.SAP_API_URL + "/SalesOrderSet",order,httpOptions).subscribe(
      (res)  => {
        console.log("salesOrder"+res);
        return "success ";
      }, (err) => {
        console.log("-- -- "+JSON.stringify(err));
        return "error";
      }
    );
  }
```

But the response is 403: Forbidden
response:
[image]
I have also tried sending withCredentials:true but it says
response:
[image]
[image][image]
If I need to add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true where to add that ?

Comment: You need to configure the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"  in your backend. is your backend Python Django or .net?

Comment: PHP laravel. Even If put Access-Control-Allow_Credentials:true CSRF token validation is failed

Comment: Can you check that API on Postman and then let me know the result here, please?